# Fetch API failed using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, fetch-api

I tried to fetch some data from an API. Here is the general link  `http://cdnapi.pressbox.com.gr/ajax/getTvProgram.php?date=YYYY-MM-DD`

and this is my code:

```
<script>

var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
document.write(today);


console.log(fetch('https://cdnapi.pressbox.com.gr/ajax/getTvProgram.php?date='+today));


</script>
```

at my console I get the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

Comment: fetch returns promise. You should do the call like this: `fetch('https://cdnapi.pressbox.com.gr/ajax/getTvProgram.php?date='+today) .then(response => console.log(response));`

Comment: returns promise but not 200

Answer (score 0):

Your first issue is that console.log() is a synchronous operation, but fetch is an asynchronous API. So fetch just returns a Promise, which console.log does not wait to resolve, before printing to the console. Your code should take advantage of asynchronous patterns, like the below.

```js
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

fetch('https://cdnapi.pressbox.com.gr/ajax/getTvProgram.php?date='+today) // request the data (async)
  .then(res => res.json()) // convert the respsonse from a bytearray into json (async)
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data) // log the data when we finally have it (sync)
  });
```

I don't believe this will work on stack overflow as I get a CORS error, but if this still doesn't work for you please share the API documentation so we can take a closer look at what's going wrong.

Comment: I still dont get data. I still see the errors. You get data when you run it?

Comment: No, as I said I get a CORS error. Are you sure that the environment you're running this script in has permission to access the data?

Comment: maybe the `+today` is a problem to the api?

Comment: No, that resolves into a regular URL string before the fetch API gets a hold of it. You are hitting CORS issues. Please look into CORS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors and review the API provider's CORS policies.